# Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/plain - AFNetwork POST

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I had install AFNetwork 3.1 by CocoaPods.
When I call the post method i hit the error as below:

> Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/plain

Here is my code to call the post method:

> AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]
>   initWithBaseURL:url];
>
> manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
>   manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
>   manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
>   manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 60;
>   manager.securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = NO;
>
> [manager.requestSerializer
>   setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
>
> ```
> [manager POST:urlStr parameters:parameters progress:nil
>       success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
>
>           NSLog(@"%@ success, responseObject: %@", url, responseObject);
>
>
>       } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
>
>           NSLog(@"%@ error: %@", url, [error localizedDescription]);
>
>       }];
> ```

How do I resolved this issue?

Comment: You are expecting json, but you are getting plain text from server.  In place of application/json try this: [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

Comment: Yes, thanks for help. I had solved the issue, please refer my reply answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, server in plain text. So I need to setup the response serializer accept content type plain text.

> manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet
>   setWithObject:@"text/plain"];